# Get content:// Uri from File

Tags: android, file, uri

I have a `File` object and I want to get its Uri, that looks like:

```
content://media/external/images/media/2683
```

I've tried the following code:

```
val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity, "${BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID}.file_provider", pictureFile)
```

But I'm getting this:

```
content://my.package.name.file_provider/external_files/Pictures/photo-1574403815163.jpg
```

Is it possible to get the Uri I need?

**UPD:** The reason I want to get another Uri - I can't create File object from this Uri later.

```
val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity, "${BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID}.file_provider", pictureFile)
val file = File(uri.path)
```

When I try to `file.exists()` I'm always getting `false`.

Comment: What **exactly** is the problem with using the `Uri` from `FileProvider`, since that is the correct solution?

Comment: @CommonsWare I can't create File object with this Uri. Maybe I do it wrong, but I always get File.exists() == false

Answer (score 0):

> I can't create File object with this Uri

That's because you don't do that. Moreover, you don't *need* that. `pictureFile` is a `File`.

Comment: As I said - I need this File later, maybe when you close app and run it again. I want to save Uri in the SharedPrefs and get it later.

Comment: @Den: You are welcome to save `pictureFile.getAbsolutePath()` to `SharedPreferences`, if you like. That is a valid filesystem path that you can use with the `File` constructor to get a `File` object back.

Answer (score -1):

If your are creating file with actual path then you just concad the content:// to that path

Iam not sure this is correct method or not but i get that what you expected , Try this one